# an attempt was made to request new permissions for a session that has a pending request.Android

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have implemented fb integration and i am getting users details by setting some permissions but it is giving me error **java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Session: an attempt was made to request new permissions for a session that has a pending request.**
when i run first time and second time it it is not giving me this exception, i am using the latest fb SDK for integration. I'll post me code.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button loginbtn;
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        loginbtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.loginbutton);


        loginbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,FacebookLogin.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

    }


}
    public class FacebookLogin extends Activity{

    Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session
              .NewPermissionsRequest(this, Arrays.asList("email,user_birthday,user_location,user_hometown,user_about_me,user_relationships"));



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.facebooklogin);

         Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

             // callback when session changes state
             @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")

             @Override
             public void call(final Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
               if (session.isOpened()) {
                  // Log.i("session.isOpened", "session.isOpened");
                   session.requestNewReadPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);
                 // make request to the /me API
                 Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                   // callback after Graph API response with user object
                   @Override
                   public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {

                       //session.requestNewReadPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);


                       //System.out.println("Response : "+response.toString()); 
                       Log.i("Response", response.toString());

                     if (user != null) {
                      Log.i("USERName", ""+user.getName());
                      Log.i("Birthday", ""+user.getBirthday());
                      Log.i("LastName", ""+user.getLastName());
                      Log.i("FirstName", ""+user.getFirstName());
                      Log.i("getId", ""+user.getId());
                      Log.i("email", " "+user.getLink()+" email : ) "+user.asMap().get("email"));
                      Log.i("location", ""+user.asMap().get("location"));
                      Log.i("gender", ""+user.asMap().get("gender"));

                       /* Intent i =new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                        startActivity(i);*/

                        finish();

                     }
                   }
                 });



               }
             }
           });


    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        Log.i(" onResume()", "called");

    };


    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        Log.i(" onStart", "called");

        super.onStart();

    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

    }


    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        Log.i("onActivityResult", "called");

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);


        final Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

        if (session.isOpened()) {
            session.requestNewReadPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);

           // make request to the /me API
            Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

              // callback after Graph API response with user object
              @Override
              public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                if (user != null) {

                     //session.requestNewReadPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);

                     Log.i("USERName2", ""+user.getName());
                      Log.i("Birthday2", ""+user.getBirthday());
                     Log.i("LastName2", ""+user.getLastName());
                     Log.i("FirstName2", ""+user.getFirstName());
                     Log.i("email2", " "+user.getLink()+" email : ) "+user.asMap().get("email"));
                     Log.i("location", ""+user.asMap().get("location"));
                     Log.i("gender", ""+user.asMap().get("gender"));

                       /* Intent i =new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                        startActivity(i);
                        finish();*/
                        //Log.i("USERName", ""+user.getName());
                }
              }
            });


          }else {

            finish();
        }


    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        Log.i("onSaveInstanceState", "called");
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

        Session.saveSession(session, outState);
    }


}
```

Comment: anyone guide me plz ??

Comment: try this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17878500/facebook-post-on-your-behalf-is-not-working-in-android-facebook-sdk-3-0-2?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the Active Session using onActivityResult method.

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
   Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);

}
```